# How to structure my database so that only logged in user can add, delete, or edit only their posts?

Tags: database, postgresql, express, authentication

I am using Express.js to make a Web App and am learning authentication using passportjs. I basically have a crud web app that lets me edit, delete or add anything from my web app by anybody. Here is what my Postgres database looks like.

```
  \connect usertesterdb;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   username VARCHAR(255),
   email VARCHAR(255),
   password TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
  );
```

And

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mymenutable (
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   foodtitle VARCHAR(255),
   fooddescription TEXT,
  );
```

What would be the best possible way so that I can achieve my goal? At the moment, the two tables are not communicating with each other. I would appreciate some strategies or good practices that would make the code clean and maintainable.

EDIT: I am thinking I could add another column in my "mymenutable" called "userid" which references the id number of the user from "users" table and then every time the user creates or edit or delete their posts or menus, it checks whether the logged in user's id is equal to the menu's "userid". I don't know if this would be the right way to do it or if it can be manipulated somehow.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/.  I have never done any express.js, but 2 minutes in Google gave me this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local and https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#postgresql and many more

Comment: craftdeer, what exactly do you want to do ? Let people create their own menu and only they can edit ? or can multiple people edit one menu ?

Comment: @baar i want people to be able to create their own menus and edit or delete only their posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding a *foreign key* to `mymenutable` would be the canonical and best way to associate a user with every entry:

```
ALTER TABLE mymenutable
   ADD COLUMN userid bigint REFERENCES users(id);
```

You should fill the column for the existing rows and then set it `NOT NULL`.

This is off topic, but I would do away with the `UNIQUE` constraint on `password`. I think it serves no good purpose, but apart from that it is a clear security risk: Users can find out the password of other users by setting their own password what they guess might be somebody else's password — an error means that they have found one.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will move with the idea. And will remove the unique constraint. idk what i was thinking.

Comment: Oh, another side remark: use `NOT NULL` on as many columns as possible. It will make your data better and your queries simpler. Also, it is much easier to drop a `NOT NULL` than to add one.

Comment: I was thinking of taking care of that by doing `required` on the forms in the front end in all fields. Should i still use `NOT NULL` in the back-end too?

Comment: Definitely. This is defensive programming. My observation is that if NULLs are allowed, you'll end up with some NULLs. Test data, manual interventions, ...